# My Basic App has a few errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a beginning coder, and while building a basic Android app in Eclipse, I encountered a few errors. The issue is that my `activity_main`, my `main`, and my `options_menu` are all unable to be resolved or not a field.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.options_menu) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `import android.R;`

Comment: Why is your code enclosed in a JavaScript code block? It won't run!

Comment: After I removed import android.R;, new errors sprung up. The R. files are now errors themselves.

Comment: There is a problem in your xml code, I guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you got a few good answers to your question, which is great. In general when asking questions about compile errors you are getting it's important to include the text of the errors. This will help us solve the issue and will also help others find this question using a search engine when they run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove

```
import android.R;
```

import at top & replace with

```
import com.example.myfirstapp.R;
```

Restart eclipse & Clean project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error in one of your XML files. This will cause and android.r import (instead of your project import). One mistake can blow up your entire project! Also from the Android documentation:

http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

> *Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement at the
>   top of your files that use resources,
>   especially when you ask Eclipse to
>   sort or otherwise manage imports. This
>   will cause your *make* to break. Look
>   out for these erroneous import
>   statements and delete them.*

While going through the Android sample tutorials, I would often use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> command to "Organize Imports" and generate any missing import statements. Sometimes this would generate the incorrect import statement which would hide the `R.java` class that is automatically generated when you build.